# How do I make the following heading output the title in an h4 tag instead of h2 using a child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I want the sidebar heading to be in an h4 tag [this is how the site structure is currently looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ldyx.png)

Here is the code where the title is being pulled from :

```
genesis_markup(
[
    'open'    => '<aside %s>' . genesis_sidebar_title( 'sidebar' ),
    'context' =>  'sidebar-primary',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `genesis_sidebar_title_output` filter to modify the output of `genesis_sidebar_title` function.

Use the snippet below to switch the tag for all sidebar titles to h4:

```
<?php
add_filter('genesis_sidebar_title_output', 'so_modify_sidebar_title', 10, 2);
function so_modify_sidebar_title($heading, $id) {
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    
    $name = $id;

    if ( array_key_exists( $id, $wp_registered_sidebars ) ) {
      $name = $wp_registered_sidebars[ $id ]['name'];
      $heading = '<h4 class="genesis-sidebar-title screen-reader-text">' . $name . '</h4>';
    }

    return $heading;
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot @Saqib Appreciate it, man! And for the footer title is the code similar too?